# Bootstrap collapse() and flash of unhidden content

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

Using Twitter Bootstrap framework, I'm using `$('#foo').collapse()` to make an FAQ with collapsable answers that are hidden by default, and then visible when you click the question.

The problem is that I get a flash of all the content before the `.collapse()` is initialized.

I can't hide the content in advance (via `display: none`), otherwise the collapse function doesn't know the height of the boxes and collapsing/expanding doesn't work.

I think this could be solved if `$('#foo').collapse()` didn't animate the initial collapse, and just instantly hid the elements.  Any idea on how to do that (or other solutions)?

Here's a fiddle to play with: http://jsfiddle.net/DHZNv/44/

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this the behavior you want?

> http://jsfiddle.net/DHZNv/45/

Comment: Well ... yes.  But you've basically just added all the data-* attributes directly to the HTML, whereas I need to do that programmatically.

Although ... did solve it by removing the "in" class from the answers, and skipping the call to `.collapse()`, so thank you for the hints.

Final fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/DHZNv/47/

Comment: A link to a potential solution is always welcome, but please [add context around the link](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/8259/169503) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there. Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline. Take into account that being _barely more than a link to an external site_ is a possible reason as to [Why and how are some answers deleted?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers).