# Bootstrap 3 collapse - flicker of hidden content on page load

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I am building an admin dashboard with Bootstrap 3, and require a "View More" button to un-collapse some content. This works fine with the following code, however on page load we see the collapse content momentarily whilst the animation takes place.

A fiddle can be found here: http://jsfiddle.net/sSNG4/

And I initialise the collapse with the following code:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".collapse").collapse();
}); 
</script>
```

Does anyone know how to remove that flicker of un-hidden content?

Note: [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11164172/bootstrap-collapse-and-flash-of-unhidden-content) refers to Bootstrap 2, and the problem was never completely fixed with a correct solution anyway.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#collapse-usage

1. In your HTML, change `class="collapse in"` to `class="collapse"`. The `in` class indicates that it's "open".
2. Remove the JavaScript completely. The `data-` attributes will tell Bootstrap to initialize the collapsible div automatically.

http://jsfiddle.net/mblase75/YyKhH/

Comment: Superb, thank you. So with the class "in" I was loading it as open then reaching the end of the page and closing it again? Genius.

Comment: I've always thought the "in" class was a poor choice of name. It's not intuitive to me at all.

Comment: I look at it and read it all as one phrase, collapse in, which is why I thought it was necessary. Do you know, whilst I have you, if it's possible to toggle the text on the View History button whilst the collapsed text is showing?

Comment: AFAIK, Bootstrap doesn't include any such functionality, which isn't to say you couldn't create your own. I'd start by reading the "Events" section under "Usage" in the docs.